# How to not get lost reviewing Gerrit reviews comments?

Tags: gerrit, review

Hey guys I'm having a problem forgetting to answer gerrit reviews comments. I'm wondering if there is any way to summarize all gerrit comments (from all patch sets with its respective replies). Let me give a example:

1. Me -> P1
2. Review1 -> comments 1a, 1b, 1c;
3. Me -> P2 (without answer any comments)
4. Me -> P3
5. Me -> 1a done, 1c done;
6. Me -> P4
7. Review1 +1, +2, finished;

How can I see that we forget to address the comment 1b ?

Bye

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. In Gerrit database, there's no difference between "answered" comments and "not answered" ones.

Take a look at the patch_comments Gerrit table:

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| line_nbr              | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| author_id             | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| written_on            | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| status                | char(1)      | NO   | MUL |                   |                             |
| side                  | smallint(6)  | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| message               | text         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| parent_uuid           | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| change_id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0                 |                             |
| patch_set_id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0                 |                             |
| file_name             | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| uuid                  | varchar(40)  | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| range_end_character   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| range_end_line        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| range_start_character | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| range_start_line      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: How come if the comments appears as reply from the previous one ?

Comment: Although there is a button called "Reply" there's no link between the old message and the reply one. They're shown stacked because they're assigned to the same line and orded by creation date. I updated the answer with the patch_comments table columns.

Comment: I see. But many isso can be resolved by retrieving the comments by file_name + line_nbr + written_on? Is there any special search that I can gave a custom select query?

Comment: You can't perform a regular Gerrit search (using the Gerrit search bar) for file_name + line_nbr + line_nbr. To learn more about Gerrit search, take a look at this document: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html